# how to check for correct query and error handle it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

With my api i have `'/api/students'`
 will produce all student names and when a req.query is input such as a name the endpoint becomes `'/api/students?name=John'`if the req.query was "John". i have used regex to check and control the input to only allow characters and spaces

```
const re = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
if (!re.test(name)){//error code
```

this will allow me to check that numbers or special characters aren't being input but if the user input the endpoint accidentally as `'/api/students?firstnames=John'`for instance, they will receive all names as per '/api/students' instead of it error handling and returning it as a bad request?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your issue is with the query param `name` vs the query param `firstnames`. In my opinion, you should not let the user decide which query param types (e. g. `name`, `age`, etc.) he can input, but rather control that in the UI (this is what you commonly see as "filters" on websites).

It sounds to me, that the API is ignoring the unknown query param `firstnames`, so it responds with all students. You could catch any unwanted query params in the API endpoint implementation, as in responding with a `400 BAD REQUEST`, once the API receives an unknown query param type, such as `firstnames`.

As to "how to check". I think you are on a pretty good path with your regex for checking the actual values of the query params. Depending on the solution you pick (UI side checking, API side checking, or both) you can do the following to control the query param types:

UI side:

1. Don't let the user freely type query param types
2. Take user input for specific query param types such as `name`
3. Compose your query string for specific query params with user input respective to the params

API side:

1. Check query params for validity (they can not be unknown)
2. Respond with `400 BAD REQUEST` if there are any unknown query params in the query instead of ignoring the unknown query params

Comment: yes but say user puts a typo in url : url/api/students?names=John instead of name. how would we check the query name and compare it with express without the server responding with all names by default. yeah focussing on server side not ui.

Comment: So I'm guessing you are using express.js for your API implementation. The request query is an object see here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req -> what you could do is read all object properties of req.query, compare them with an array of known query params and throw an error, if there are any unknowns.